# Incomplete ResultSet on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a JNDI JDBC connection pool on Tomcat hosted on an Amazon Web Services EC2 talking to an Amazon Web Services PostgreSQL Relational Database.

I have a table with 40,000 rows of data that I am attempting to collect in one go using a JDBC PreparedStatement "SELECT * FROM tableName".

This combination of things works flawlessly, collecting all 40,000 rows, when I run the servlet on my local machine (from my local Tomcat) and have it talk to the RDS via *db-name.aws-rds-URL*:5432, however, when I run the same servlet on my AWS EC2 and instruct it to talk to the RDS on its local vLAN, it never gets more than 30,000 rows, with resultSets as few as 2,000 rows.  Each time I refresh it, it yields a new and different, yet incomplete, number of rows.

Below is my entry in Tomcat's global context.xml (I am using the same dataSource across multiple servlets).

```
< Resource
name="jdbc/postgres4"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="8"
maxIdle="8"
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
url="jdbc:postgresql://dn-name.aws-rds-URL:5432/SID"
username="db-username"
password="password" />
```

Any ideas on what could be going astray here?

Comment: fetch size maybe? not sure but maybe amazon has some timeout set for your query (elastic = nothing can take too long) - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/jdbc-fetch-size-parameter.html

Comment: Yea, I tried using a 1,000; 10,000; and 40,000 fetchSize, to no avail :(

Comment: The client-size out-of-memory error is something that I need to investigate, since I am using a micro EC2 instance currently.

Comment: What's your exception handling? It seems to me like you should be seeing an error here, with an SQLException thrown. I'm wondering if you're swallowing exceptions somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions.  I am pretty sure that I have all of the Postgresql/servlet exceptions going into a log file, and the only entries are my debug entries saying: DB row nums: 13786   Servlet row nums: 13786, etc.  By every normal right, it works flawlessly, but it just doesn't finish the job...  I tried flipping the * out for the column names to see if the JDBC binding was mucking things up to no avail either.  I will keep plucking away at it.

Comment: The DB row nums is from the ConcurrentMap.size() inside of the rs.next() loop that .puts() the rs values into the ConcurrentMap, and the servlet row nums is from database engine return value for this specific method.

Comment: I just touched the problem now.  I think my ConcurrentMap is not putting reliably.

Comment: Many thanks to Craig for making me think in another direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a database issue at all...  I added a counter to the while(rs.next()) loop and I ended up with 40,000 every time, while the servlet row nums varied as before.

I managed to fix the issue by switching from the Google Guava MapMaker() ConcurrentMap to the Java ConcurrentHashMap, except now I have to deal with the Java HashMap GC memory issue again...